# Music file secure link PHP

Tags: php, api, security

I am developing a music application and my job is to secure audio sources for download. URL is hostname/music/get/5 which 5 is music id.

The backend finds music and sends it to the frontend.
But users can download files using this link. Please, give me advice to this problem.

```
$filename = $file->link;
$length = $file->size;
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *');
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
header('Content-Range: bytes 0-' . ($length - 1) . '/' . $length);
header( 'Content-type: audio/mpeg' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: inline;filename="'.$filename.'"' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$length);
$link = str_replace(' ', '%20', $filename);
readfile($link);
```

Comment: Use a link with a random alpha-numeric string, not id. And use a database table to convert between that random string and the real id.

Comment: If you don't like unauthorized users downloading files, you need some kind of authentication system.

Comment: do users need to log in? if so, is there a way to check the session data to see if they are logged in, and have access to this file? I would think that would be the way to go.

Comment: @ITgoldman i would think random links probably isn't the best way to go for securing an asset. what happens when users start posting the links all over the internet for people to use freely?

Comment: It's not about users posting freely the links, it's about non wanted users downloading all songs by the predictable `id` of them. Ideally user would have to be logged in, yes.  But otherwise it's a good enough solution.

Comment: Which kind of attack you want protect against? You want to prevent unauthorized people to download music? Do you want to forbid users to download music files instead of listening to them? can you be more specific?

Comment: You can make it harder for someone to get the music file directly from a link, but you can never secure that content as you are given access to that content. It's in a browser... it's on client side, it passes through its audio board and it can be stolen. Even Netflix has this problem, I can always record a movie that streams on my device.

Answer (score 0):

you can use token authentication or something to secure files

read
https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php